# "A way" or "any way" , what is correct?

Tags: grammar, determiners, adverbial-phrases

What of these is correct? and if both are correct, what is there any difference or connotation in the meaning? or, are there different in terms of formality?

- Is there **a way** you could send me the documents earlier?
- Is there **any way** you could send me the documents earlier?

Also, wondering, do I need to use *that* before *you could* ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Both are valid and correct. The second might be slightly more natural.
2. The second one might carry a *slight* emphasis on how desperate you are to get them (though the first one is already *implying* the same hurry). It's like a reduced version of "Is there *any* way, even if it's not easy or obvious, even if you already told me it's impossible, *any* way under heaven by miraculous or superhuman effort, that this could be done?"
3. No, you don't have to include "that" before "you could," though it wouldn't be a problem if you did.
4. Both are equal in formality. In terms of tone: both of these *somewhat* soften your request (compared to "Could you send me the documents earlier?"), but they're also a *little* bit "pushy." If you want to emphasize politeness rather than urgency, you could say something like "Might it be possible for you to send me them earlier?"

Comment: You have a good answer here.  I would add that I feel that "any way" suggests that you are looking for one or more possible solutions, and hoping that such solutions actually exist.  Similarly but subtly different, "a way" suggests to me that the speaker suspects that you, personally, have a secret method that has sofar been withheld, and you are asking/hoping that this one method will be used now.  The singularness of "a way" vs "any way" is what makes it more direct to me.

Answer (score 1):

Since they are both hypotheticals, they both work the same.

Technically, **a way** is asking for *one possible* way, while **any way** suggests there are *many possible* ways.

They both seem to be non-literal ways to ask the question:

- **Can** you send me the documents earlier?

because this statement can sound like a command, so people will use "is there a/any way".... in front of their request instead.

Comment: Exactly, I should have given the context. Yes I am trying to induce the other party's conversation to send me the documents earlier. So I understand from your answer, both work pretty much the same, right?

Comment: @Curious, yes I think they both work pretty much the same